# Select count where two columns aren't equal to 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as below mentioned:

```
|----------------|-------------|-------------|
|      a_id      |     m_id    |   e_id      |
|----------------|-------------|-------------|
|       1        |       1     |      0      |
|       2        |       2     |      2      |
|       3        |       3     |      3      |
|       4        |       1     |      1      |
|       5        |       4     |      4      |
|----------------|-------------|-------------|
```

I need a query that performs the task that `a_id` should have either `m_id` or `e_id` not equal to 0.

So, I wrote the query as follows which returns count 5:

```
SELECT count(a_id) from ids where (e_id!=0 or m_id!=0)
```

I need `a_id` should have distinct `m_id != 0`. That should return count 4.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `count(distinct`

```
select count(distinct m_id) from ids where e_id!=0 or m_id!=0
```

Comment: Though sample data doesn't reflect this, but i think you must include the condition in your answer as `m_id != 0`